# Java Triangle task

Tags: java

I have task to implement some methods to make math operations and etc. I'm fine with that part. But I cannot get how and where I have to create other part of code to make program working. Do I have to create Point objects by myself to access cordinates to make calculation?
How can I access `x` and `y` of each Point in `public Triangle`?

```
class Triangle {

    public Triangle(Point a, Point b, Point c) {
        //TODO
    }

    public double area() {
        //TODO
    }

    public Point centroid(){
        //TODO
    }

}
```

```
class Point {
    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point(final double x, final double y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }
}
```

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        {
            double area = new Triangle(new Point(0, 0), new Point(3, 0), new Point(0, 4)).area();
            System.out.println(area);
        }
        {
            Point centroid = new Triangle(new Point(0, 0), new Point(3, 0), new Point(0, 3)).centroid();

            System.out.println(centroid.getX());
            System.out.println(centroid.getY());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The `Triangle` class can store the points passed to the constructor as member variables.

Comment: As @JohnnyMopp says. And then you can call the `getX` and `getY` methods on those points in the methods in `Triangle`.